# MySQL query from 2 tables confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I have a query that I would like to run but is not returning the expected results.

So my tables are like this

```
users (has two columns)
user_id,name

users_archive (has the same two columns) 
user_id,name
```

I want to basically run a query that lists user_id from the respective table where the username matches what I'm searching for

For my example I have a user called MikeBOSS in users_archive with an user_id of 123 (there is no MikeBOSS in users table)

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_archive.user_id 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_archive ON users_archive.name='MikeBOSS' 
WHERE users.name='MikeBOSS';
```

but that returns no results

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_archive.user_id 
FROM users, users_archive 
WHERE (users.name='MikeBOSS' OR users_archive.name='MikeBOSS');
```

That returns a bunch of results from the users table that are incorrect.

Could someone maybe point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Is there no relation between 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want a JOIN, you want a UNION. Look

```
SELECT users.user_id, 'users'
FROM users 
WHERE users.name='MikeBOSS'
UNION 
SELECT users_archive.user_id, 'archive'
FROM users_archive
WHERE users_archive.name='MikeBOSS';
```

Comment: Thanks so much. you are correct UNION is exactly what I was looking for. I tried some of the other JOIN examples but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

A join condition normally links two tables.  Yours does not:

```
ON users_archive.name='MikeBOSS'
```

A join condition that does link the two tables might look something like:

```
ON users.name = users_archive.name
```

If you wonder about the number of rows this returns, check each table individually.  Is there even a row with `name = 'MikeBoss'` in the `users_archive` table?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_archive.user_id 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_archive ON users_archive.name='MikeBOSS' 
WHERE users.name='MikeBOSS';
```

To

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_archive.user_id 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_archive ON users.name = users_archive.name WHERE users.name='MikeBOSS';
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this could work if you have no relation between 2 tables. Using left join gives you record from one table even if its not present in other.

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_archive.user_id 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_archive ON users.userid = users_archive.userid and users.name = users_archive.name
WHERE users.name='MikeBOSS';
```